# Jquery error in reloading javascript function trying to load json data with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to visualise a folder structure with javascript and json. It automatically loads the root of the folder. When a user clicks on a folder, it should load the files and folder in that folder etc.

The javascript code to get deeper in the json works fine, it loads the first "layer" of the json file with the variable "root". If I change this manually to "roots.deeperFolder" it reaches that folder. That's works fine.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'directory.json',
    data: {
    get_param: 'value'
    },dataType: 'json',
    success: buildRoot
});
```

Code for ajax reaquest and call buildRoot function if succes.

```
function buildRoot(root, clickedFolder){

    if (typeof root === 'string') {
            var addFolder = "." + clickedFolder;
            var stringRoot = root + addFolder;          
            var root = eval(stringRoot);
            console.log(stringRoot);
        }

    $.each(root, function(index, element){

        if (isNaN(index)) {
            $("#sideFolderContainer").append("<li class='folder' id=" + index + ">" + index + "</li>");
        }
        else {
            $("#sideFolderContainer").append("<li>" + element + "</li>");
        }
    });

}
```

This function succesfully iterates through the first layer of the JSON file. The "if string" function only applies after click function.

```
$(document).on('click', '.folder', function(e) {
    var root = "root";
    var clickedFolder = $(this).attr("id");
    buildRoot(root, clickedFolder);
});
```

This function sends the "deeper folder" information to the previous buildRoot function. The buildRoot function adds the name of the deeper folder to root. (root.deeperFolder) what manually works.

I guess passing through the data between the function is not the problem since this works fine. I get the errors at this line:

```
 $.each(root, function(index, element){
```

This is what the console outputs (ignore first line).
[image]

Link to JSON data.

http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/f56dce

Answer (score 2):

I do recommend to use **JSON.parse(jsonString);** instead of **eval**.

I thing this is a better approach. (see the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/))